# How to get rec script of SOX to work on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, sox

I built sox for `Android` and I am using the generated binary files i.e. `sox, rec, play and soxi` generated directly in my app  by installing them as binaries within my app.

I am able to invoke commands using `sox` directly however I have a problem in invoking `rec` command.

I used the following command, `rec -r 8000 -c 2 output.wav`
But it fails saying that `sox is not found` or `sox is expected but is not found`.

The above rec command works perfectly in Ubuntu when I use it in command line

Please note that I am able to use operation related to `sox` binary successfully, but I am unable to use commands related to `rec` binary.

Initially I thought the problem may be because of permissions imposed by Android so I included these permissions in `manifest.xml` but to no avail.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

I did some research and got this [link](http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/SoxTutorial.html), it says in section **Using Sox to Play and Record** that there might be some Linux systems which do not accept `rec` command directly.

I followed his suggestion and appended my commands with `padsp` etc, but it still doesn't work.

So my question is how do I invoke rec command successfully on Android system, has anyone tried this before?

Comment: Could you share how you generated the binary files for android, I am trying to do the same thing without success.  Thanks

Comment: @InonStelman and Arif Nadeem, can you share me the process of getting the binaries of sox in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rec`, `play`, `soxi` are symbolic links to the `sox` binary. (Alternatively, on platforms that don’t support symbolic links, they are all identical copies of the same binary.) SoX has a different default behaviour depending on the name by which it is called.

It seems that something is wrong with the symlinks on your device. Perhaps they are pointing to the wrong path? Try if you can fix this.

Your other option is to use the `sox` binary for all tasks. `rec -r 8000 -c 2 output.wav` is actually the same as `sox -d -r 8000 -c 2 output.wav` (`-d` is the default audio device). For playback, similarly, `play somefile` is the same as `sox somefile -d`.

Comment: I am thinking that perhaps rec, play and soxi being sh files can be run as scripts

Comment: There is really no shell script involved. Try `ls -l /usr/bin/rec` to see that it is just a symlink. _If_ they are shell scripts in your installation, it’s a modified version.